# Scroll page as parallax scrolling

Tags: html, css, scroll, parallax

I have this html tag

```
<a class="drop1" href="#div3" ><span>Services</span></a>

<div id="div1"> --- Some Code To be executed --- </div>
<div id="div2"> --- Some Code To be executed --- </div> 
<div id="div3"> --- Some Code To be executed --- </div>
```

**Question:** my question is this when I click on link page should scroll down as parallax scrolling. Suggest me simple css code.

Comment: You should use some JavaScript libraries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use html anchor

```
 <a class="drop1" id="here" href="#div3" ><span>Services</span></a>    
    <a name="div1"> --- Some Code To be executed --- </a>
    <a name="div2"> --- Some Code To be executed --- </a> 
    <a name="div3"> --- Some Code To be executed --- </a>
```